# Vite Vue Multi-pages doesn't work properly with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I add nested page as it said [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) and it works great. Then I add new route (e.g. path is **/nested/some-route**). If I open **/nested/** then go through RouterLink to **/nested/some-route**, I see correct page. But if I open **/nested/some-route** directly, I see 404 error because original entry (index.html, not nested/index.html) is processed.

I created github project for easy reproduction of this bug:
https://github.com/marvel-code/vite-vue-router-bug

Comment: If this a bug of vite-vue-router combo?